# This login script

Tags: php

I was learning to make a simple login form from a book and I'm having some problems.

When I run the login.php script in my browser and enter the correct username and password(or even a wrong input)..it displays the error

> (Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\rassal\login.php on line 8).

If I enter the correct combination, the user is logged in ..but still the same notice appears and the script redirects back to the login.php page.

How can I edit the script to make it work perfectly ? Like it should accept the login and then take to a page(in session).

Here are the codes

login.php

```
<?php
$username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$redirect = (isset($_REQUEST['redirect'])) ? $_POST['redirect'] : 'secret.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged']!=1)
{
if(!empty($username) && $username == 'uname' && !empty($password) && $password = 'ppas')
{
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
$_SESSION['logged']=1;
header('Refresh: 5; URL = '.$redirect);
echo "Redirecting";
die();
}
else
{
$_SESSION['username']='';
$_SESSION['logged']=0;
echo "You entered a wrong combination of username and password";
}
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username :</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the auth.inc.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged']!=1)
{
header('Refresh: 5; URL=login.php?redirect=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
echo "You'd be now redirected to the login page ";
}
die();
?>
```

and here's secret.php(file to be shown when the user has successfully logged in )

```
<?php
require ('auth.inc.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Logged IN </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>You're now logged in </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you writing this without indention, or is it just the copy/pasting that has bugged out? Using proper formatting and an IDE (netbeans is free) really helps out a in readability and later on when you come back to edit your code. On topic: you should start all your files with "session_start();"

Comment: You should place `session_start` before you call `isset` on `$_SESSION['logged']`.

Comment: Where is your `session_start()`?

Comment: This question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write `session_start();` in the top of login.php after `<?php` to activate the session variable :)

Also, replace all

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged']!=1)
```

with

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || $_SESSION['logged']!=1)
```

to make sure you wont call a undefined index.

Comment: Ok, did that..but I now get this error :- Notice: Undefined index: logged in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\rassal\login.php on line 10

Comment: ..because it isn't set. It should be '||', not '&&':
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || $_SESSION['logged']!=1)

Answer (score 0):

You have not start the session that's why it is undefined to variable in you **login.php** file.

Use this in login.php file:

```
<?php
session_start(); //use this line in your login.php file at the starting
$username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
```

**EDITED:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {
  $_SESSION['logged'] = "";
}
```

Use this code.

Comment: Ok, did that..but I now get this error :- Notice: Undefined index: logged in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\rassal\login.php on line 10

Comment: @Rahul I have edited the answer, check that and use that code will work for you.